# Binding a configurable complex field to angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, model-view-controller, webforms

so i have a custom component that is a multiselect typeahead dropdown. On the pages i am calling it i have reactive form groups. I would like to bind it to a form control like you do with the mat-form-fields but im not sure how to configure the component to allow for this

big-form-one.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="groupOne">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select formControl="selectControl"></mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>    
  <app-multi-typeahead formControl="howtobindvalues"></app-multi-typeahead>
</form>
```

In this case the mat-select binds to the form control and the values become easily manageable, the validations are uniform and the events can be controlled, with the custom component i am using @Input and @Output the manage the values, and in the output function doing formControl.value = child component selected values.

Its not clean and i have to build this custom set of communications in every component that instances the typeahead.

Is there a way to make the custom component act like a form field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your component must be implements ControlValueAccessor.
this is a good article about it.
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls/

Comment: this is exactly what i did and it worked like a charm! saved me weeks of work just to change a field, thank you good sir